# Subtract timestamp having spaces in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am new to linux scripting . Please help

Below are my inputs

```
current_date="2010-06-01 09:34:59"

filedate="2010-06-01 09:32:59"
```

Now my output should as 2 minutes

I tried below code I get expr error . Please help

```
diff=$(`expr $current_date - $filedate`)
expr: syntax error
```

Comment: convert both to seconds, subtract and convert to days.  Note that the difference won't be a date.

Comment: Tried this way ns1=$(date --date "$current_date" +%s%N) and ns2=$(date --date "$file_date" +%s%N). echo "the difference in seconds is:" `bc <<< "scale=3; ($ns2 - $ns1) / 1000000000"` "seconds". Result set I get in sec how do I get in minutes ?

Comment: remove nanoseconds, your dates don't have it, unnecessary complication.  Dividing seconds to 60 will give you minutes; dividing mins to 60 will give you hours.

Comment: Like this ? echo "the difference in seconds is:" `bc <<< "scale=3; ($ns2 - $ns1) / 60"` "seconds" ?

Answer (score 0):

this is one way to do this

```
$ { date -d "$current_date" +"%s"; date -d "$file_date" +"%s"; } | 
    paste -s | 
    awk '{secs=$1-$2; mins=int(secs/60); 
          printf "%02d:%02d\n", mins, (secs-mins*60)}'
```

will give you

```
02:00
```

of course, you may want to extend to hours, days, etc.

Comment: { date -d "$current_date" +"%s"; date -d "$file_date" +"%s"; } | paste -s | awk '{secs=$1-$2; mins=int(secs/60); printf "%02d:%02d\n", mins, (secs-mins*60)}'
-4476445:-1. I am getting like this

Comment: Please help y am I getting like this I tried remving int in int(secs/60) thot might be bash dependent . But no luck .

Comment: change file_date to filedate, your variable name don't match what I have in the script.

Comment: suggestion for debugging, try each command in the pipe line one by one.